# Magento not Upgrading from 1.3.2.4 to 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.3

I am trying to upgrade Magento 1.3.2.4 to 1.7 using Magento Connect Manager via '**magento-core/Mage_All_Latest**' extension key to install. But I found the following error and I don't know how to reslove it.

Error -

**Exception caught:**

**Warning: include(/N91nq64igkwi8oxu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/projects/spacecenter/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93**

If anyone faced this kind of error, please help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend [this](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/) upgrade guide from Turnkey - worked perfectly for me.

Please don't expect that everything works or looks the same once you've upgraded to Magento 1.7. Depending on what features or extensions you use, quite a bit of work might be needed until you're done. So don't do this on your live system. Better duplicate it to a development environment and test the upgrade there.